# HTML multiple tooltip on a single image is not working properly on any browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm facing problem in jquery tooltip. I have single image which I divided in five rectangle part with the of coordinates. My tooltip is working but I'm not getting tooltip at position where i want. All tooltip show at same location.

Here it is my html code for multiple tooltip on single image. In Firefox not showing any tooltip or in Google Chrome it shows all tooltip on upper-left side.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Ciclo</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/tooltips.css'>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if !IE | (gt IE 8)]>!-->
        <script src="js/tooltips.js"></script>

        <script>
                $(function() {
                    $("#Map a[title]").tooltips();
                });
        </script>

        <style  type="text/css">
            body{margin:0; padding:0;}
            .ciclo_image{height:600px; width:600px; margin:100px auto}
        </style>

      </head>       
      <body>
        <div class="ciclo_image">
          <img src="img/ciclo2.jpg" width="600" height="600" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
          <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <a href="#" title="Market"><area shape="rect" coords="83,91,193,174" href="#" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Arising"><area shape="rect" coords="333,59,473,153" href="#" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Reprocessing"><area shape="rect" coords="5,318,141,385" href="#" /></a>
            <a href="#" title="Collection"><area shape="rect" coords="480,302,578,373" href="#" /></a>      
            <a href="#" title="Shorting and Trading"><area shape="rect" coords="227,491,379,555" href="#" /></a>
          </map>
        </div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: provide a jsfiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a map, href attributes goes in area tag

If you want to show those tool tips, you'll need first to give them a display value.
This will only work in opera and chrome/safari (windows as far as i've tested)

example on dabblet : http://dabblet.com/gist/5586117 you'll see  map and area styled or not from a browser to another.

Absolute positionning with coordinates makes it work.

I believe you should make your map with div and links in absolute position with image as background.

Comment: my positions are working good i think there is some problem in my jquery

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7yBj/). You need to add jquery.ui.js in your page.

Use custom code while appling tooltip to HTML element.

```
    $(function() {    
              $( 'document' ).tooltip({      
                            position: {        
                                    my: "center bottom-20",        
                                    at: "center top",
                                    using: function( position, feedback )
                                               { 
                                                    $( this ).css( position );         
                                                    $( "<div>" ).addClass( "arrow" )
                                                      .addClass( feedback.vertical )
                                                      .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
                                                      .appendTo( this );        
                                                }      
                                       }    
               });  
 });
```

You can change style for tooltip as per your requirement. Also you can select specific selector on which you want to apply tooltip. I used 'document' as a selector.

Comment: still its not working friend.i think there is some problem in jquery and it shows error on fire bug as The "coords" attribute of the <area shape="rect"> tag is not in the "left,top,right,bottom" format.

Comment: did you check my jsfiddlw? it is working there perfectly. coords is not used these days. use left,top,right,bottom. or margin.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this markup

```
   <area title="Market" shape="rect" coords="83,91,193,174" href="#" />
   <area title="Arising" shape="rect" coords="333,59,473,153" href="#" />
   <area title="Reprocessing" shape="rect" coords="5,318,141,385" href="#" />
   <area title="Collection" shape="rect" coords="480,302,578,373" href="#" />  
   <area title="Shorting shape="rect" coords="227,491,379,555" href="#" />
```

I think some issue in function also

tooltip not tooltips

```
   <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#Map area[title]").tooltip();
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: tooltips() is correct. after using tooltip() it showing an error on firbug as TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function

Comment: add ui js
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
along with jquery

Comment: ya add that js too still its not working and showing an error on firebug as The "coords" attribute of the <area shape="rect"> tag is not in the "left,top,right,bottom" format.

Comment: ya i check your jsfiddle but still its not fullfill my requirement i want that each tooltip show on different different position

Comment: i checked your fiddle its good and i want same on my project too still its not working for my project code

Comment: shinov its working good on Chrome but in Firefox it shows an error TypeError: window.event is undefined